# how to set background duration in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('div').css('background','#fff').delay(12000).css('background','#000');
});
```

Hi mates.. I'm wondering why this doesn't work.. I'm trying to set the duration of my background and change its color after a specific time.

Comment: `delay` only affects effects like animations.

Comment: hi @musa.. can you recommend any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try setTimeout

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var divs = jQuery('div').css('background','#fff')
    setTimeout(function(){ divs.css('background','#000'); }, 12000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with pure CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/austinpray/Q8TVX/

```
 body {
  animation:color-change 5s 1;
  -webkit-animation:color-change 5s 1; /* Safari and Chrome */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes color-change
{
  0% {background:#fff;}
  90% {background:#fff;}
  100% {background:#000;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes color-change /* Safari and Chrome */
{
  0% {background:#fff;}
  90% {background:#fff;}
  100% {background:#000;}
}
```

You can change the animation properties to get your desired effect.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: thanks for you help @Austin Pray.. but I want to consider IE8.. anyway that also helps.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) only works with jQuery's standard effect queue or a custom queue, you probably just want to use a `setTimeout()` call.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('div').css('background','#fff')
    setTimeout( function(){ jQuery('div').css('background','#000'); }, 12000);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/CLG95/)** (with three second timeout to see more quickly)

Comment: Silly that we need to write (I do it too) obvious things like `(with three second timeout to see more quickly)` :D

Answer (score 0):

jQuery delay function will execute subsequent functions in the queue. So you have to queue it:

```
$('div').css('background','#fff').delay(12000).queue(function(nxt){
     $(this).css('background','#000');
     nxt(); // continue the queue
 });
```

Try [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tatE4/3/)

Hope this is helpful for you.